# how to set the selected value in mvc webgrid during the model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Any one help me to select the value in drop down for a given model value. I am trying to bind the mvc webgrid using my rolemodel,it has rolename, roleid etc., every roleid have role id and i want to show the role id as selected value in my drop down. currently the below code showing only first name in the list as default selected value for all the user.

```
 grid.Column("RoleName", "RoleName", format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode">
                     <label id="lblRoleName">@Html.DropDownList("UserRoles", (SelectList)ViewBag.UserRoles)</label>
                 </span>
                <input type="text" id="RoleName" value="@item.RoleName" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),
```

code in controller

```
using (var context = new FloorContext())
            {
                var userRole = (from role in context.Roles select role).ToList();
                ViewBag.UserRoles = new SelectList(userRole, "RoleId", "RoleName");
            }
            var reportObservable = GetReportObservable();
            ViewBag.Roleobservable = reportObservable;
            return PartialView(reportObservable);

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Since your question is about the dropdown, can you post the code where you construct ``ViewBag.UserRoles``

Comment: you have to do selected where you are populating drop down select list data